# Salesforce APEX update when null

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

Okay so I asked this question a few weeks back and I got some great help - But I'm still not 100% there with regards to the problem I keep having...Any help would be great...
I'm still having major trouble with this code and could use some more help...

For some reason it is still changing any numbers to 0 not just adding a zero to a null field.

If I have 4 LOC's with the following - 
Competitor Sold Rate
150, 125, 0, Blank or Null
Lost
False, True, True, False
I want them all to be marked Lost and I only want the last Competitor Sold Rate to be marked 0

Currently all mark Lost and All change to 0 - I know the code does the update because if I change the code to say make them 10 they all update to 10

Please any help would be wonderful...

trigger updateLOConLostOpportunity on Opportunity (after update) {

```
//The map allows us to keep track of the opportunities that have been lost
```

Map oppsWithStageLost = new Map();

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
    if (   (Trigger.old[i].StageName != 'Lost')
        && (Trigger.new[i].StageName == 'Lost')) {
        oppsWithStageLost.put(Trigger.old[i].id,
                              Trigger.new[i]);

    }                          
}
List<Line_of_Coverage__c> updatedLOCs = new List<Line_of_Coverage__c>();
for (Line_of_Coverage__c loc : [SELECT id, Lost__c, Opportunity__c
                                  FROM Line_of_Coverage__c
                                  WHERE Opportunity__c
                                    in :oppsWithStageLost.keySet()]) {
    Opportunity parentOpp = oppsWithStageLost.get(loc.Opportunity__c);


     loc.Lost__c = TRUE; 

     if (loc.Competitor_Sold_Rate__c == NULL) {

         loc.Competitor_Sold_Rate__c = 0;

     }  


    updatedLOCs.add(loc);

}
update updatedLOCs;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add Competitor_Sold_Rate__c  to select query

```
for (Line_of_Coverage__c loc : [SELECT id, Lost__c, Opportunity__c,Competitor_Sold_Rate__c  
                                  FROM Line_of_Coverage__c
                                  WHERE Opportunity__c
                                    in :oppsWithStageLost.keySet()])
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the type of Competitor_Sold_Rate__c?  If it's a string or a picklist, it may never be set to null specifically -- you may have better results comparing it to the empty string ''.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm not understanding the question correctly, but if I am you want the sold rate = 0 only for the last element, you can try this. Also like the other post mentioned you would have to include Competitor_Sold_Rate__c in the query

```
List<Line_of_Coverage__c> updatedLOCs = new List<Line_of_Coverage__c>();
list<Line_of_coverage__c> locs = [SELECT id, Lost__c, Opportunity__c, Competitor_Sold_Rate__c
                              FROM Line_of_Coverage__c
                              WHERE Opportunity__c
                                in :oppsWithStageLost.keySet()]; 

for (Integer i = 0; i < locs.size(); i++) {
  Opportunity parentOpp = oppsWithStageLost.get(locs[i].Opportunity__c);
  loc.Lost__c = TRUE; 

  //check if it's the last loc -- size would return 4
  if (loc.Competitor_Sold_Rate__c == NULL && locs.size()-1 == i) {
    loc.Competitor_Sold_Rate__c = 0; 
}  

updatedLOCs.add(loc);
.
.
.
```